# Rich TextBox accepting Script tags also

Tags: asp.net, richtextbox, freetextbox

I have a aspx form where we have used freetextbox as my rich text editor to make entries.

but I am able to enter `<script></script>` in this reach tags.

how can i validate on client side that it should not accept any scripting which ever it is included in javascript library.

EDIT:

how can i validate it for not allowing script tags into it?
how can we validate it for mandatory field?
How can i manage more than one `textareas` on my page. but i want only one to be as rich editor and not all???

I had tried some code but it did not helped me for proper validation. below is the snippet. 
**SCRITPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $btn = $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>");
        var $txtEditor = $("#<%=txtEditor.ClientID %>");

        $btn.click(function () {
            alert($txtEditor.html()); 
            return false;
        })

    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
        <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" />

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do need support HTML in your text, then you probably should integrate some WYSIWYG editor ([TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) for example).

If you don't need html there, then just html encode all user input.

Comment: is this free, can we use it for developing the website for our clients and host their website on internet. Or do we have any license for this. please give the details. it is fantastic...

Comment: its free and you can deploy it with your app, it just have some extra payed plugins, but for basics you won't need them

Comment: added more queries after using TinyMce. Can you help me in this?

Comment: can you please guide me more on this?

Comment: Tried a lot and all my Questions were solved.. Thank you so much... @syl

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the content and allow only *white listed* markup.

There are are [numerous ways of getting script to execute](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) in arbitrary markup (without necessarily needing <script> tags). Blacklisting isn't a viable solution if you're trying to avoid XSS attacks.